Is it "banknote" or "bank note"?
Which form is correct, the one-word "banknote" or the two word "bank note" and why?
Does correctness depend on region, such that one form is correct in one country, while the other is correct in another country?
I appreciate that in common written language the two forms are used interchangeably, at least in my area (eastern Canada), but on closer inspection, some individuals consistently use the one-word form, while others use the two-word form. I wonder if anything at all can be inferred about the individual based on their use of this term.
Legislation in the English language in Canada uses the two-word form:

"cash" means coins referred to in section 7 of the Currency Act, notes issued by the Bank of Canada pursuant to the Bank of Canada Act that are intended for circulation in Canada or coins or bank notes of countries other than Canada

At the time I asked this question, there were 10 search results using the "bank note" form, 14 using "banknote", and none using both forms in the same question/answers.
The generic question from 13 years ago, When should com­pound words be writ­ten as one word, with hy­phens, or with spaces? is of no help. I'm not looking to learn how to properly speak the language, but for an explanation on why this particular word is spelt on way or the other. Both forms are in common use, and I am hoping that some regionalism is to blame.
As I mentioned, the purpose of the question is to help me understand if I can infer from a particular individual's preferred spelling anything about the individual (like where he is likely from). I hope to use this understanding in connection with other linguistic forensics tools to identify one particular individual across several written samples.

What about bank-note?

Is there a part of the world where the hyphenated form is in current use? I have seen it in very old texts, but is it a modern contender?

The hyphenated form had some currency a century or two ago. But we don't even use the single-word form much today. Probably partly because context nearly always makes it clear when notes means banknotes, so why bother with the first word anyway? But nobody really cares how you write a term like that, and I think it's unlikely any style guide would go to the trouble of ruling on it.

Related and possible duplicate.

M-W has it open (bank note) when listing types of notes with two words that can't be closed. So you can just open it for consistency if you're M-W, or anybody. 'I would rather have a bank note than a love note.' But banknotes leave me wanting more. Nobody wants to see 'euro bank note.' It seems like 'scot sheep dog.' Surely, that's not right.

You're asking whether "bank + note" is a compound noun or a syntactic construction. The two bases are inseparable, so it's the former, and should be written as the lexicalised "banknote". See here: link and here: link and here: link and here: link

There is an evolution of words: word1 word2 is instigated to convey an idea. When the idea is useful/common, it attempts the transition to word1-word2 and then to word1word2. The evolution is not tidy and, often for no apparent reason, speakers choose the one that "looks right to them". Eventually, the word may establish a set form, however, as English has no governing body, this does not always happen and  the separate forms coexist. The idea that the transition is "regional" has no basis in fact - you can read words written by people from all over the world.

@HippoSawrUs ??? << banknote [noun]: a promissory note issued by a bank payable to bearer on demand without interest and acceptable as money >> [M-W]; no spelling variants offered.

Dictionary.com sees that the open form (outlawed by some dictionaries) is used by a reasonable number of people who don't subscribe to the CGEL embargo on open compounds. And Google ngrams (see Henry's answer) show a significant minority opting for this form.

@EdwinAshworth - You didn't dig deep enough. I can find anything. I think you should take it up with them while IDC enough. https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/note#legalDictionary I always get the multiple question marks…Why???

@HippoSawrUs I didn't dig deep enough? I looked in the obvious place (you failed to give a reference at that point). It would seem you missed the obvious. // That aside, M-W is obviously inconsistent.

@EdwinAshworth - I didn't dig deep enough = I looked in the obvious place. That's consistent. Call M-W inconsistent, but when I'm looking for types of notes, I look under note. I could look under foot, but that would be too deep and Autocorrect couldn't handle it.

@HippoSawrUs Banknote/bank-note//bank note (probably not recognised by CGEL) are variants of a compound noun. Why would one look this up under 'note'? I don't look 'guinea pig' up under 'pig'.

What Is the Difference Between a Bank Note & Currency? https://www.sapling.com/7897829/difference-between-bank-currency

I doubt it matters as you will be understood, though hyphens seem to be  least-common according to these Google ngrams.
The Bank of Canada issues bank notes/billets de banque and may prefer the space in English to match those in French. If you are in Canada, this option may therefore be easiest to justify.
The Bank of England issues banknotes.
The US Federal Reserve Banks issue notes.


banknote (n.)
(1) As two words or with hyphen. A promissory note given by a banker,
payable at a fixed date to a specified payee. Now historical and
rare.
See note at sense 2.
1695 A Bank Note for 17l. 2s. 4d. payable to Philip Wheake.
London Gazette No. 3046/4
(2) A piece of paper money of a fixed denomination, circulating as
currency. Also figurative. Cf. note n.2 V.21a.
During the 18th and early 19th centuries, there was a gradual
transition from sense 1 to this sense, as banknotes developed from
being promissory notes, on which the sum payable and the name of the
payee were written by hand, to being fully printed pieces of paper
currency in specific denominations (technically constituting a central
bank's promissory note to pay the stated sum to the bearer on demand).
By 1745 the Bank of England was issuing notes in fixed denominations,
although the signature and the name of the payee were added by hand;
the first fully printed Bank of England banknotes were issued in 1853.
The U.S. Treasury first issued fully printed banknotes in 1862.
In North American usage the usual term is now bill (bill n.3 9c); see
also bank bill n. 1
1759 The gentleman..very complaisantly told me, I had won the wager;
at the same time putting a twenty pound bank-note into my hand, for
which I gave him change.
Life & Real Adventures of Hamilton Murray vol. I. xix. 231
[OED online]


Cambridge Dictionary does not have an entry for bank note, only for

banknote
a piece of printed paper that has a particular value as money

In UK a banknote still has a declaration like

I promise to pay the bearer on demand the sum of ten pounds.

Which at one time was followed by the signature of the Chief Cashier (of the Bank of England), now in a different place. There are other UK banks which issue banknotes too.
A page from the Bank of England begins

The Bank of England note: a short history
Before the establishment of the Bank of England in 1694, banking in England had been virtually restricted to the goldsmiths in London . . . their promissory notes payable on demand, which were issued to depositors, had come to be used as a convenient means of making payments and could, if desired, be cashed in part only. It is from these goldsmiths' notes that the Bank of England note ultimately derives.

This bank note was a virtual currency, well before the computer age. It was just a piece of paper.
Over time, the term 'bank note' is becoming 'banknote' and the usage is shown by Google Ngram Viewer.


No difference, contracting words together with nothing, or a hyphen, or not doing so entirely and just using a space is extremely normal in English. "banknote", "bank-note", "bank note", etc…
